# Package Import error on Golang

Tags: go

My post has 2 question

I'm essentially trying to understand how to use gomock with gingko

GOPATH

`/Users/Ratatouille/Desktop/test/goExample`

The following project is located at

`/Users/Ratatouille/Desktop/test/goExample/square`

which has following project structure

```
.
├── area.go
└── area_test
    ├── area_mock.go
    ├── area_mock_test.go
    └── area_suite_test.go
```

what I'm not able to understand why I'm getting following error

```
Failed to compile area_test:

can't load package: package ./area_test: found packages area_test (area_mock.go) and area (area_mock_test.go) in /Users/Ratatouille/Desktop/test/goExample/square/area_test

Ginkgo ran 1 suite in 303.243871ms
Test Suite Failed
```

my second question is project repo has area.go file which look like this

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Square struct {
    side float32
}

func (s *Square) Area() float32 {
    return s.side * s.side
}

func (s *Square) CalculateArea(shaper Shaper) float32 {
    shaper.Area()
}

type Shaper interface {
    Area() float32
}

func main() {
    sq1 := new(Square)
    sq1.side = 2

    var areaIntf Shaper
    areaIntf = sq1
    fmt.Println(areaIntf.Area())
}
```

My question is how do I **import** `main` package inside `area_mock_test.go`

Comment: As far as I can see, package name of `area_mock.go` should be area not area_test. And package name of `area_mock_test.go` should be area_test not area.

Comment: @mattn why is that I'm kind of relatively new in go. my understanding is that `package` name mention inside the file take the package under which the file belong. And area_mock.go has `package 'area_test'`

Comment: You workspace setup is totally wrong. Your go source code files go below $GOPATH/**src**. Read https://golang.org/doc/code.html and stick to to it. And please take a look at how the std lib does it's testing. That's how it is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project structure isn't the one Go expects.

`area_test/` are not the tests for `area`. I'm going to guess you ran `go test ./area_test`. That tells Go that `./area_test` is a project. It tried to compile `area_mock.go` and tried to use `area_mock_test.go` and `area_suite_test.go` as its tests. The error you got is Go's awkward way of telling you that it did not expect to find a package named `*_test` in a project file.

---

`area.go` is also a problem. You have it using `package main`, but then try to test with `package area_test`. They don't match and Go won't like it. A package directory contains ***one package***. Its tests must use either that package or `thatpackage_test`. This enforces that a package directory does one thing. Its either a library to import, or its a program to run. Not both.

Also the project directory is called `square`, but the package is `area`. It's ok to have files that don't match the project name, and its fine to have multiple files in one package, but using a package than the project directory name is not good practice.

---

There's another problem. Go expects source files to be in `$GOPATH/src`. You have them directly in `$GOPATH`. Import statements won't find them.

---

Go's project structure can take a bit of getting used to, and it has very firm ideas about how projects and packages are to be structured (Go has very firm ideas about how code is to be written, and how it isn't). Don't fight it. Do yourself a favor and use the default `GOPATH` of `~/go` and put your code in `~/go/src/`.

You'd write the square library like so.

```
~/go/src/square/
|--- square.go
|--- square_test.go
```

square.go might look like this.

```
package square

type Square struct {
    Side float32
}

func (s Square) Area() float32 {
    return s.Side * s.Side
}
```

Note that `Side` must be capitalized for it to be a public data member. Also note that its passed by value, in Go the style is to only pass by pointer if you intend to modify the struct.

square_test.go might look like this.

```
package square_test

import(
    "testing"
    "square"
    "github.com/stvp/assert"
)

func TestArea( t *testing.T ) {
    sq := square.Square{Side: 5}

    assert.Equal( t, sq.Area(), float32(25) )
}
```

Go does not come with any asserts. [`github.com/stvp/assert`](https://github.com/stvp/assert) provides the basics and removes a lot of tedium. You can get it with `go get github.com/stvp/assert`.

Note that it is in `package square_test` to make this a blackbox test which can only use the public interface of `square`. If you wanted a glassbox/internal test, it would use `package square` and go in its own file like `square_internal_test.go`.

If you want a program that uses square, that would be in its own separate package directory. It would have a `main.go` with `package main` and `import "square"`.

[How To Write Go](https://golang.org/doc/code.html) explains this in more detail.

Comment: Schwern For development purpose do one always have to do `go build` for packages. one can just import without `go build` as well right ?

Comment: @Ratatouille: `go build` or `go install` is how you compile the code, or you could also run `go test` if everything you want has a test fixture. What would it mean to import code without compiling it?

Comment: @Ratatouille Yes, `go build` will build any imported packages, if necessary.